# telegrapher's equation redcation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The telegrapher's equation in its generalized form is:
$$c^2u_{xx}=u_{tt}+au_t+bu$$
If we apply transformation $v(x,t)=w(t)u(x,t)$, then according to this [paper](http://www.math.umbc.edu/~jbell/pde_notes/07_Telegrapher%20Equation.pdf)
if $b-a^2/4=0$, we can reduce the telegrapher's equation to the wave equation.

However, in my homework, $b-a^2/4=0$ condition is not satisfied, do we have other ways to reduce telegrapher's equation to standard 1D wave equation?

Let's consider this equation:
$$u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}+2u_t+u$$

how to reduce this equation to the form of :
$$u_{tt}=Constant\cdot u_{xx}$$
I have tried $v=w(x)u(x,t)$ and $v=e^{(px+qt)}u(x,t)$, both failed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=e^{-\frac{at}{2}}v$ ,

Then $u_t=e^{-\frac{at}{2}}v_t-\dfrac{ae^{-\frac{at}{2}}v}{2}$

$u_{tt}=e^{-\frac{at}{2}}v_{tt}-\dfrac{ae^{-\frac{at}{2}}v_t}{2}-\dfrac{ae^{-\frac{at}{2}}v_t}{2}+\dfrac{a^2e^{-\frac{at}{2}}v}{4}=e^{-\frac{at}{2}}v_{tt}-ae^{-\frac{at}{2}}v_t+\dfrac{a^2e^{-\frac{at}{2}}v}{4}$

$u_x=e^{-\frac{at}{2}}v_x$

$u_{xx}=e^{-\frac{at}{2}}v_{xx}$

$\therefore c^2e^{-\frac{at}{2}}v_{xx}=e^{-\frac{at}{2}}v_{tt}-ae^{-\frac{at}{2}}v_t+\dfrac{a^2e^{-\frac{at}{2}}v}{4}+ae^{-\frac{at}{2}}v_t-\dfrac{a^2e^{-\frac{at}{2}}v}{2}+be^{-\frac{at}{2}}v$

$c^2v_{xx}=v_{tt}+\left(b-\dfrac{a^2}{4}\right)v$